# Number of trials needed to reach a probability P of a randomly thrown ball landing in each of four buckets, with constant success rate Q.

Tags: probability

Suppose a ball is randomly thrown at a collection of four buckets. The ball has a probability of 1/25 of going into each of the buckets. How many shots must be taken to have a 50% of the ball having landed in each bucket?

I believe this problem best fits the coupon collector's problem, but a geometric distribution will not work because the probability of each bucket is different and does not sum to 1. I'm unsure how to use the maximum-minimums identity approach, but it seems like that would work here.

$$
E[X] = \int^{+\infty}_0(1-\prod_{i=1}^4(1-e^{-0.04x})dx)
$$
$$
E[X] = 52.08
$$

https://mat.uab.cat/matmat_antiga/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz I edited the post.  That pdf does a good job explaining the situation, but I'm still unsure.

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially the coupon collector's problem, as you noted.

The probability that the ball falls in a bucket is $\frac4{25}$, so the expected number of throws until it first falls in a bucket is $\frac{25}4$.  Now the probability that the ball falls in an unused bucket is $\frac3{25}$, so the number of additional throws until he ball falls in the second bucket is $\frac{25}{3}$.  Continuing in this manner, the expected number of throws until a ball falls in each bucket is $$25\left(\frac14+\frac13+\frac12+1\right)$$

Comment: That's the exact same answer I got using the integral above. Seems strange!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the maximum-minimums identity approach, but if both methods solve the same problem, it doesn't seem at all strange that they get the same answer.  My approach seems much simpler and straightforward than solving that integral.  Just looking at the integral, I'd guess that the maximum-minimums is somehow related to the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  (Maybe the same, in disguise.)